# Check if Applet is Active in chrome using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, applet

I have defined an applet in object tag.
In my JavaScript function I want to check if applet s already active/loaded. 
For this, I tried document.HelloWorldApplet.isActive() but it does not work in chrome, but it is working in IE.

Below is the code

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <TITLE>New Document</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<SCRIPT>
  function waituntilok() {
    if (document.HelloWorldAppletId.isActive()) {
      doit();
    } else {
      alert('in else');
      settimeout(waituntilok(), 5000)
    }
  }

  function doit() {
    alert('in doIt');
  }
</SCRIPT>

<BODY onLoad="waituntilok();">
  <b>HELLO WORLD APPLET</b>
  <object id="HelloWorldAppletId" name="HelloWorldApplet" classid="clsid:CAFEEFAC-0017-0000-FFFF-ABCDEFFEDCBA" width="100" height="100">
    <param name="java_code" value="com.sample.HelloWorldApplet.class"></param>
    <param name="java_codebase" value='.'></param>
    <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.4"></param>
    <param name="cache_archive" value="HelloWorld.jar"></param>
    <param name="persistState" value="false" />
    <param name="cache_option" value="yes" />
    <param name="ARCHIVE" value="HelloWorld.jar"></param>
    <param name="scriptable" value="false"></param>
    <param name="MAYSCRIPT" value="true"></param>
    <param name="java_showprogress" value="true"></param>
    <param name="java_appletname" value="HelloWorldApplet"></param>
    <param name="java_preloadjars" value="HelloWorld.jar"></param>
  </object>


</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Please suggest how do I proceed with this?

Comment: Resolved this problem, by changing <object> tag to <applet> tag.

Answer (score 1):

From JS, call a custom method of the applet (e.g. `isAppetLoaded()` that returns false before `init()` is called and `true` afterwards).